Can I resubmit my ESTA application?
I have entered in my ESTA application that I went to Cuba 2023. Therefore, my ESTA has been rejected. Can I resubmit the ESTA with having gone to Cuba 2019? There are also no stamps in my passport, even though I have had that since 2022. Or will this result in my being banned permanently from getting an ESTA or even entering the US altogether?

Why did you even apply? Did you not notice the info link on the ESTA/CBP web page, that takes you to a FAQ on how Cuba’s designation as a State Sponsor of Terrorism impacts travel to the US under the VWP? And having told them you travelled there, how could you think that the notion of resubmitting with different information is even remotely feasible?

A very literal answer to the question: Yes, you can re-submit your application. Is it a good idea: NO! (I think the major reasons have been mentioned).

If you have visited Cuba in 2023, then you can't change anything about that.
Lying on an ESTA (or visa) application is the kind of thing that will get you banned for years if you get caught (banned from entering the US altogether). And since you already gave them different information, the chances they will find out are quite high.
You need to apply for a visa (and be truthful on your application).

One of the statutory grounds of inadmissibility in US immigration law is deception.  There is no time limitation to the inadmissibility.  If someone is found to have used deception, they must either get the finding overturned or receive a waiver.  Overturning the finding is virtually impossible for a nonimmigrant who is outside the US as there is no right to court access, and the waiver process is entirely at the discretion of the consular officer with little or no public information available about how they evaluate waiver applications.  I would avoid a finding of deception at all costs.
